# Angular upload Image and save it in spring-backend

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Angular/Spring and have to store (H2-Database) an image (jpeg/png) and I am not quite sure how I should manage to do this.
I get my file in the template as:

```
<input #img type = "file"  accept="image/jpeg,image/png"  (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

My component-class looks like this:

```
private userDto: User = {
    id: 0,
    name: null,
    img: null
  }

  save(name:string){
      this.userDto.name = name;
      this.userService.saveUser(this.userDto).subscribe(
        newUser => this.createdUser = newUser)
  }

  onFileSelected(event){
    this.user.img = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

And my service(simplified):

```
saveUser(user: User): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(this.userURI, user);
  }
```

I catch the post in Spring using  @PostMapping/@RequestBody.
My question now is: Which type do I have to send and use in Angular and Spring [java], that I can store the image in the backend and display the image I just stored when it is returned. (Or what I am doing wrong?)
Sorry for the maybe dump question, but I never used neither Angular or Spring before.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: In the frontend you usually have a blob, in the backend a byte[] for the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uploadFile( file: File , id : number ) : Observable<any>  
  {  
    let url = this.baseUrl + "uploadImage/" + id ;  

    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();  

    formdata.append('file', file);  

    return this.http.post(url , formdata);  
  }
```

the file argument of type File is retrieved in event.target.files.item(0)

check this for more details : https://www.javatpoint.com/angular-spring-file-upload-example